# Trying to implement a simple "check the redux store first" observable in RxJS 5

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have the following scenario in an Angular 2 app:

1. I have a list of items loaded async into a redux store when the app loads
2. A user navigates to a route that displays a single item

What I'd like to implement using rxjs is if the item the user has requested is already in the store, then simply return it. Otherwise, make an HTTP call to load the specific item requested.

In many cases the item needed will already be in the store, but if they navigate directly into the CRUD page, then there's a chance it's being loaded, but just isn't there yet. If we're using paging, then it's possible it *won't* be there even if the items have finished loading. In either of those two cases I just want to make an HTTP call directly for the item.

I was hoping to use some sort of observable chain to check the store for the item, and if it's not there immediately, then flatMap using a angular2 http call that'll return the item.

Any I thinking about this right, and is there a simple set of operators that can do this?